# Place Html code in between php loop

Tags: php, html, loops, mysqli, radio-button

I have a while loop in php and want to place radion buttons in between . Something like this:

```
     <?
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE `type` IN 
    ('".implode("','",$fin_element)."')";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    echo "check 1";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "check 3";
    echo "Q:" . $row["question_name"]. "<br>";
    <UL>
        <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="question1" VALUE="answer1.1">
            <?php  
                echo "am i visible?";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                echo "id: " .$result->fetch_assoc()["answer1"]. "<br>";
            ?><BR>
        <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="question1" VALUE="answer1.2">
            <?php  
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                echo "id: " .$result->fetch_assoc()["answer2"]. "<br>";
            ?><BR>
        <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="question1" VALUE="answer1.3">
            <?php  
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                echo "id: " .$result->fetch_assoc()["answer3"]. "<br>";
            ?><BR>
        <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="question1" VALUE="answer1.4  ">
           <?php  
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                echo "id: " .$result->fetch_assoc()["answer4"]. "<br>";
           ?><BR></UL>
      }
    } else {
           echo "0 results";
           }

   ?>
```

But here the code from

```
    <UL> to </UL>
```

does not work

Actually im making a quiz question which is fetching question and answers from database, and here **fin_element** consist of list of id to fetch questions respectively, so at a time multiple questions with there answers should be fetched. please help.

Comment: You can't just wrap any elements in `<ul>`. `<ul>` is the parent of an unordered list. You need to have `<li>`'s (list elements). Like this: `<ul><li>...your code...</li><li>....</li></ul>`

Comment: yes i know that's why want to know some resolution...

Comment: If you know it won't work, why do it? You need to wrap each row in `<li>....</li>` and it should work. I also can't see any opening `<ul>` element in your code. You should read up on HTML lists: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

Comment: You also haven't closed your PHP-block before writing your HTML.

Comment: There are too many issues here. You're outputting HTML inside a PHP block. You're then opening a new PHP block inside another PHP block. You have invalid HTML etc. You're using short tags (`<?`) to open the first PHP block (which is turned off as default in newer versions of PHP).

Comment: actually i have taken a part of code from in between where im facing issue that's why mussing closures

Comment: If you have removed parts of the code here and there, it's impossible for us to help you. We need to see the _actual_ code. All the relevant and intact code. How would we know where you've missed something or where you have removed something? It's just a waste of time. You should also expand on what _"does not work"_ mean. We're not mind readers. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 5):

You can end your php tag after curly bracket of while loop

```
    <?
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE `type` IN 
        ('".implode("','",$fin_element)."')";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        echo "check 1";
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
```

and create php tag just before ending of while loop

```
   <?php  
       }
} else {
       echo "0 results";
       }
```

Comment: `<? php` = Syntax error. You need to remove the space: `<?php`. This is also far from the only issue.

Answer (score 1):

you have to generate radio code.

like the below code

```
$count = 1;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Q:" . $row["question_name"]. "<br><UL><li><INPUT TYPE='RADIO' NAME='question".$count."' VALUE='answer".$count.".1'>"."id: " .$row["answer1"]. "</li><li><INPUT TYPE='RADIO' NAME='question".$count."' VALUE='answer".$count.".2'>"."id: " .$row["answer2"]. "</li><li><INPUT TYPE='RADIO' NAME='question".$count."' VALUE='answer".$count.".3'>"."id: " .$row["answer3"]. "</li><li><INPUT TYPE='RADIO' NAME='question".$count."' VALUE='answer".$count.".4'>"."id: " .$row["answer4"]. "</li></UL>"
$count = $count+1;
}
```

Comment: yes I will correct that didn't observe. and while you submit you will have an issue as all the questions will have the same radio button name that will cause problem so use counter to name the radio button differently for different questions. :)

Comment: for question1 you will have 4 option right, and for question 2 you will have 4 option right. so question 1's 4 options are radio button with same name. so for question 1 = 4 radio button name = question1, and question 2 = 4 radio button name = question2. this is how it should be!!

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I read your code completely wrong. This is actually completely correct. I'm blaming that it was early in the morning here and that it was pre-coffee :-)

Comment: no problem, we are here to learn. mistake happens even by me. you know you corrected my code that I missed `<li>` thanks for that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your concept, as I am low on reputation so cn't comment it, but the line you wrote here

```
<UL> to </UL>  does not work
```

Actually it won't work as You can't just wrap any elements in `<ul>`

only thing you can do is by

```
<?php
echo '<UL><LI><INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="question1" VALUE="answer1.1">';
//another php code goes here
echo '</LI></UL>';
?>
```

Also you can do is:

```
<?php
echo '<ul>';
while()
{
 //your loop goes here
  echo '<li>';
  //your code
  echo '</li>';

  echo '<li>';
  //your code
  echo '</li>';
}
echo '<ul>';
```